# Facebook batch API not returning user email id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am using FB batch API for user login,and this is the API call

```
$queries = array(

array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/home?limit=50'),
array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/photos?limit=6'),

);

// POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
try{
 $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');

 }catch(Exception $o){
 error_log($o);
}

//Return values are indexed in order of the original array, content is in ['body'] as a JSON
//string. Decode for use as a PHP array.

$user_info  = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], TRUE);
$feed   = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], TRUE);
$friends_list = json_decode($batchResponse[2]['body'], TRUE);
$photos   = json_decode($batchResponse[3]['body'], TRUE);
```

When I print the user_info variable `print_r($user_info)` I get this array,but it does not give me the user **email id**.I am not sure why?I went through the documentation but didn't find a solution.How can achieve this?
If its due to authentication,how can I send a trusted parameter to the API and does the authentication apply only to email address and not to other fields?

```
Array
(
[id] => 1000015567757
[name] =>Name
[first_name] => First name
[last_name] => Last name
[link] => http://www.facebook.com/sach.ch
[username] => sachtawa
[birthday] => 12/13/1987
[hometown] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1000015534545
        [name] => Patna, India
    )

[location] => Array
    (
        [id] => 106442706060302
        [name] => Pune, Maharashtra
    )

[gender] => male
[timezone] => 6
[locale] => en_US
[verified] => 1
[updated_time] => 2012-12-13T04:11:12+0000
)
```

Thank you for the attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a users email you need the appropriate permission https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions

meaning you must explicitly ask for permission to read it

Comment: Thanks for the inputs,but still I am struggling to achive this.I used the `parse_signed_request` function,but I get an error of function re declare,and if I print the request array I get multiple fields in the array,followed by the above error.It would be helpful if you tell me what functions I need to use to achieve it.Actually I am new to it and trying to learn how this feature works.

Comment: What user permissions do you ask for from your users when you get them to authorise your app?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs,I was able to achieve using a different API provided by FB for the updated security patches by them.